# How to update a single value in a Laravel Session Array?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Session array like this:

```
[
    {
        "itemId": "1",
        "itemQuantity": "3",
        "itemName": "Item_name1"
    },
    {
        "itemId": "2",
        "itemQuantity": "2",
        "itemName": "Item_name2"
    }
]
```

How can I update the quantity of a single item if I know the `itemId`?

I know that one way of doing this would be to fetch the whole array, loop through the array, make the updates and 'put' the entire array back into the session.
Is this the only way?

I'm a beginner. Please help out.
Thanks.

Comment: In case you're using the array session driver, that I'm afraid that's the only option.

Comment: What other driver can I use? Thanks!

Comment: Hey there. Out of curiosity, is your `itemId` auto-incrementing? If it is, how did you achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference so you can simply do this.

```sql
foreach(Session::get('cart') as $item) {
    if ($item->itemId == '2') { // say we  want to double the quantity for itemId 2
        $item->itemQuantity = $item->itemQuantity * 2;
        break;
    }
}
dd(Session::get('cart'));
```

Output:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#162 ▼
    +"itemId": "1"
    +"itemQuantity": "3"
    +"itemName": "Item_name1"
  }
  1 => {#163 ▼
    +"itemId": "2"
    +"itemQuantity": 4  <<--- the quantity has been doubled
    +"itemName": "Item_name2"
  }
]
```

Comment: @peterm I'm trying something similar but I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error on line 
` $item->itemQuantity = $item->itemQuantity * 2; `

Comment: @peterm yes, I'm just not sure why it happens since my code is based on yours:

`foreach(Session::get('cart.program') as $item){
    if ($item->id == '1xxx') {
        $item->segment_weekday = '9';
        break;
    }
}`

Comment: @peterm var_dump(Session::get('cart.program')):

`array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '1xxx' (length=4)`

Comment: @peterm Thanks for your help. I can access array members, just can't figure out how to pass `$item` by reference `&$item` to save back to session.

Comment: @peterm Created a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887608/save-new-value-to-laravel-session-array/31887705#31887705