# Save new value to Laravel session array

Tags: php, arrays, session, laravel

I have the following code where I loop through the items in the session array and change the value. How can I save it back to the session?

```
foreach(Session::get('cart.program') as &$item) {
    if ($item['id'] == '1xxx') { 
        item['id'] = '2xxx';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @peterm I posted a new question. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it

```
$cart = Session::get('cart.program');

foreach($cart as &$item) {
    if ($item['id'] == '1xx') { 
        $item['id'] = '2xx';
        break;
    }
}

Session::put('cart.program', $cart);
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought there would be a way of modifying and storing just one item in the array but this works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Session::put()` to [save to the session](http://laravel.com/docs/master/session#basic-usage) in Laravel:

```
foreach(Session::get('cart.program') as $item){
    if ($item['id'] == '1xxx') { 
        Session::put('cart.program.id', '2xxx');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't update `$item['id']`. It adds `"id" => "2xxx"` as a new item to `cart['program']`

Comment: I've seen the Laravel docs on working with session data but I'm not sure about the syntax for updating the value of item in the loop.